# Does Arduino support the struct hack or similar solution in lieu of flexible array elements?

Tags: struct, arduino, flexible-array-member

I coded an Arduino project for my son and learned about C in the process. All works fine but after dividing up the code into ten files and grouping the variables into structs in each file I'm not able to solve one wish for clarity. We need to empirically determine the best size of an array for storing and averaging port reads so this is what I want:

```
struct Alarms {
  // Configurable parameters
    const unsigned int number_of_reads = 24;
  // State variables
    int reads[number_of_reads]; // Error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Alarms::num_of_reads'
};
```

It’s simple but doesn't work. I tried flexible array members until I found that that feature is not supported in C++. Arduino compiles with C++. I tried many examples of the 'struct hack' but they all returned errors like this one:

```
struct Alarms {
  // Configurable parameters
    int number_of_reads = 24;
  // State variables
    int reads[];
} ar;

void setup_alarm() {
    ar.reads = malloc(sizeof(int) * ar.number_of_reads);  // Error: incompatible types in assignment of 'void*' to 'int [0]'
}
```

That looked promising but I suspect my ignorance is glowing brightly. Most struct hack examples call for declaring the struct and later initializing the struct variables. I’m hoping to not duplicate the struct.

I considered splitting the struct but that would be error prone and, well, another compile error:

```
struct Alarms2 {
    int reads[ar.num_of_reads];  // Error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
} ar2;
```

An alternative is to size the array and get the size later but it needs an explanation:

```
struct Alarms {
  // Configurable parameters
    int reads[ 24 ];  // Put number of reads to average between brackets
  // State variables
    int number_of_reads;
};

void setup_alarm() {
    ar.number_of_reads = sizeof(ar.reads) / sizeof(ar.reads[0]);  // this works
}
```

Is there a way to work the struct hack or some similar solution in Arduino to like achieve the first example?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the struct must be known at compilation time. Const data types in structs can change per instance of the structure, that is why you are getting the invalid use of non-static data member 'Alarms::num_of_reads' when you try to initialize your array. The best way to solve this is to have an `init_alarm` and `destroy_alarm` functions. Like so ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_NUM_OF_READS (24)

struct alarm {
    // Configurable parameters
    const int number_of_reads;
    // State variables
    int *reads;
};

void init_alarm(struct alarm *alarm)
{
    alarm->reads = (int *) malloc(alarm->number_of_reads * sizeof(int));
}

void destroy_alarm(struct alarm *alarm)
{
    free(alarm->reads);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // When we create our struct, set number_of_reads to default
  struct alarm alarm = {.number_of_reads = DEFAULT_NUM_OF_READS, .reads = NULL};

  init_alarm(&alarm);

  alarm.reads[0] = 13;
  alarm.reads[23] = 100;

  printf("alarm.reads[0] = %d, alarm.reads[23] = %d\n", alarm.reads[0], alarm.reads[23]);

  destroy_alarm(&alarm);

  return 0;
}
```

Note: Inorder to use the designated initializer to initialize a structure you must compile with ANSI (C99) like so ...

`gcc --std=c99 test.c -o test`

Comment: I successfully compiled and ran your interesting solution using gcc but I've got some hurdles to make it work in Arduino world. I'm working on parts of that now. The Arduino IDE does not offer compiler flag setting and main() is hidden. If I use #define DEFAULT_NUM_OF_READS (24)
 then I can just initialize the array with int reads[DEFAULT_NUM_OF_READS]. I'm hoping to reign in all value setting into the structs.

Comment: You can change the compilation flags by editing the `compiler.c.flags` variable in the `platform.txt` file. You can read more about that [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-IDE-16x-compiler-optimisations-faster-code/). If you do `reads[DEFAULT_NUM_OF_READS]` then you do not need the `init_alarm` and  `destroy_alarm` functions anymore. The size of the struct is now know at compilation time. Just know that you will not be able to change the size of your array per struct. All `alarm` structs will have a `reads` array of size 24. The answer above allows you to customize size per struct